# Does express no longer support ejs out of the box?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Does express no longer support ejs out of the box? I keep getting the below error Cannot find module 'ejs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs

It is here, probably you are doing something wrong if you are getting an error.